# Is $\mathrm{Hom}(P^i,P^j)$ a finite set? ($P=$ power set functor, $i\equiv j\bmod2$)

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $P:\textbf{Set}\to\textbf{Set}$ be the *contravariant* power set functor, and put $P^n:=P\circ\cdots\circ P$ ($n$ factors), so that $P^n$ is a covariant (resp. contravariant) endofunctor of $\textbf{Set}$ if $n$ is even (resp. odd). If $i$ and $j$ are nonnegative integers of the same parity, write $\mathrm{Hom}(P^i,P^j)$ for the collection of all morphisms from $P^i$ to $P^j$ in the appropriate category of functors.

> Is $\mathrm{Hom}(P^i,P^j)$ a finite set?

A more precise question is

> Is $\mathrm{Hom}(P^i,P^j)$ a set? If it is, what is its cardinality?

Put $\mathbf1:=\{0\}$, $\mathbf2:=\{0,1\}$. Arguing as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2087805/660) of Todd Trimble we see that 
$$
i\equiv j\bmod2,j\ge1\implies\mathrm{Hom}(P^i,P^j)\simeq\mathrm{Hom}(P^{j-1},P^{i+1}),
$$
$$
j\equiv0\bmod2\implies\mathrm{Hom}(P^0,P^j)\simeq P^j(\mathbf1),
$$
$$
j\equiv1\bmod2\implies\mathrm{Hom}(P^1,P^j)\simeq P^j(\mathbf2).
$$
We also have
$$
i\equiv0\bmod2,i\ge2\implies\mathrm{Hom}(P^i,P^0)=\varnothing.
$$
Indeed, a morphism $P^i\to P^0$ induces a morphism $P^i(\varnothing)\to P^0(\varnothing)=\varnothing$, and $P^i(\varnothing)\ne\varnothing$ if $i\ge1$.

I don't know if $\mathrm{Hom}(P^3,P^3)$ is a set, but I hope it is a *finite* set. [There are at least $2^{16}$ members of $\mathrm{Hom}(P^3,P^3)$. Indeed, $\mathrm{Hom}(P^2,P^2)\simeq\mathrm{Hom}(P^1,P^3)\simeq P^3(\mathbf2)$ is a set of cardinality $2^{16}$, and the "map" $\mathrm{Hom}(P^2,P^2)\to\mathrm{Hom}(P^3,P^3)$, $\alpha\mapsto P(\alpha)$, where $P(\alpha)$ is defined by $P(\alpha)_X:=P(\alpha_X)$, is "injective".]

Here is a variant of the above presentation.

Let $\mathcal C$ be the full category of $\textbf{Set}$ whose objects are the sets $\varnothing$, $\{0\}$, $\{0,1\}$, $\{0,1,2\},\dots$ [$\mathcal C$ is equivalent to the category of finite sets, but the objects of $\mathcal C$ form a set.] Let $\mathrm{Hom}'(P^i,P^j)$ be the collection obtained from $\mathrm{Hom}'(P^i,P^j)$ by replacing $\textbf{Set}$ with $\mathcal C$. Then $\mathrm{Hom}'(P^i,P^j)$ is a set (of cardinality at most $2^{\aleph_0}$).

> What is the cardinality of $\mathrm{Hom}'(P^i,P^j)$? In particular, is it finite?

There is a natural "map" from $\mathrm{Hom}(P^i,P^j)$ to $\mathrm{Hom}'(P^i,P^j)$.

> Is this "map" "injective"?

[In the above lines we assume $i\equiv j\bmod2$.]

Comment: `\mathrm` $\gt$ `\text` in this setting

Comment: [Related question on Mathematics Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2898227/660)